# Do various shield skills scale with armor and resistances?

Tags: torchlight-2

Do skills like Forcefield and Aegis of Fate scale with defensive stats such as your armor rating and elemental resistances?

Comment: Not directly as far as I know, but Forcefield and Aegis of Fate only apply after damage is reduced by armor and resistances.

Comment: Kind of the answer I was looking for :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aegis of Fate bases its absorption from your current armor stat.  Other than that, neither Forcefield and Aegis of Fate are directly affected by any defensive stat as far as I know.  However, they are indirectly affected as their damage absorption takes place fairly late in the damage calculation process, after most of your other defensive stats like flat armor and damage reduction have already been accounted for.  Because of this, you can consider the skills to be indirectly boosted by any defensive stats you have on the character.

Source: [How Defense Works, official forums](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=55943)